# How can Captain America's shield ricochet?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, captain-america

Captain America's shield is stated to be made at least partially of Vibranium, a material that is "vibration proof." Logically, this would mean that it dissipates all kinetic energy. However, in comics and movies, he frequently throws the shield and it bounces off of various objects (trees, vehicles, people). If the shield dissipates all vibration, shouldn't it simply impact its first target and then drop, having lost all its kinetic energy and therefore becoming unable to collide elastically?

Comment: @galacticninja possibly,  but I feel this is asking for more of a focus on how the material effects it rather than a how is it thrown?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Slightly different question, but the answers on the other one address this one.

Comment: @timpanus no need to delete.  This way anyone who finds your question will be limited in the right direction.